# markdown and enumitem: \renewlist leads to error of undefined label

Tags: errors, enumitem, markdown

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\renewlist{itemize}{itemize}{10}

\usepackage{markdown}
\begin{document}
\begin{markdown}
- ...
- ...
\end{markdown}
\end{document}
```

One would see the error

```
Package enumitem: Undefined label.
```

pointing to the line in an auxiliary file:

```
\markdownRendererUlItem ...\markdownRendererUlItemEnd
```

`\renewlist{itemize}{itemize}{10}` is essential as I need to increase the default depth of `itemize`. Is there then some way to correct this error?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand the enumitem package, declaring itemize to have 10 levels means you have to define the labels for each level, e.g.

```
\renewlist{itemize}{itemize}{10}
\setlist[itemize]{label=\textbullet}
```

Comment: For some reason this doesn't work. Actually in my actual document I already had this configured, yet the `Undefined label` error still appears :(